# Restore screen brightness automatically at boot

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia-graphics-card, brightness

I want to run this script on ubuntu 19.04, after booting the OS to restore the previous screen brightness:

```
echo 50 > /sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0/brightness
```

How can I run this script so it takes effect at the right moment?

Comment: Okay, sounds good. What's your question?

Comment: @gronostaj where to put the script to take effect.

Comment: Please put that in your question ([edit] it) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1833532 and try http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man8/systemd-backlight@.service.8.html  https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/19.04/ubuntu-main-i386/systemd_240-6ubuntu5_i386.deb.html